# Deciphering CGColor

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, cgcolor

Hi Im trying to get my head around CGColor, Ive been doing a lot of Quartz2d stuff.  In the past I've fudged it with [UIColor xColor].CGColor.... but with this new compiler I get crashes when i specify the color, ie [UIColor redColor].CGColor is fine but if I cook my own [UIColor color withRed: x Green:y etc].CGColor it crashes.  I dont think its a retain issue because [UIColor alloc]initWithRed:].CGColor gives me the same thing.   I'm guessing the UIColor -> CGColor bridge is kinda fudged, hard coded in for the preset colors only, not a conversion.   And so I'm looking for an RGB type CGColor scheme so I can reconstruct a color from an array of values.  I dont really care if its 0-1 or 1-255 etc, just need a system I can get my head around if anyone can throw me a bone I'd really appreciate it cheers

Comment: In your example your have [UIColor color withRed....]. Is that your actual code? If so, the space between 'color' and 'withRed' with cause it to crash.

Comment: I think it was a typo because in that case it woudn't compile at all.

Comment: thanks guys, yeah a typo, thats right, you can sure be sloppier in your browser than in xcode huh :D.   I really appreciate the answers, its hard to know who to give the tick to because Diego answered it very nicely, but Kevin accurately diagnosed the problem, defeating the need for even the question. :D the autorelease properties of UIColor have caused me headaches in the past, Id kind of forgotten..

Comment: In the end the best thing for me was a custom color class with +(UIColor)mySpecialColor type methods, so I can just import the header where I need it and call the right color at the time its needed, no retain issues at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it with CGColorRef CGColorCreateGenericRGB(CGFloat red,CGFloat green,CGFloat blue,CGFloat alpha);

details here: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColor/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Thanks Diego. I spent an hour or two in the CGColorSpace.h ...  wow, too many options..   Cheers a simple one that works is great

Comment: Note: CGColorCreateGenericRGB is not available on iOS, read the answer from Kevin below.

Answer (score 5):

I expect what's really going on is you aren't retaining the resulting color, and you're letting the UIColor get autoreleased. The built-in colors (e.g. `-redColor`, etc.) are likely globals that live forever, but the ones you create with `-colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` are created on-demand and autoreleased. If you pull the CGColor out of it, the CGColor's lifetime is tied to the lifetime of the UIColor, so if you're going to hold onto the CGColor past the current stack you'll need to `CGColorRetain()` it (and then `CGColorRelease()` it when you're done).

Comment: thanks Kevin, great explanation, I've had a few headaches retaining colors before. cheers